# How to create navigation forms in Ms Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I want to create 'Navigation Forms' in 'ms Access' as it should look like a form but i need to navigate in between them.
And the forms are composed of queries creation of form is simple but the problem is like if i can create in 2010 or 2013 its just simple but i dont have upgraded version but i think there is some way to create page navigation like 2010 and 2013 in 2007.

Any help is accepted.

Here is a sample link in 2010(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovcxmeyrILQ)

Comment: Got the answer tab control option in ms access 2007 does the same job with little difference

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Please **[edit]** some extra info into the body of the question for clarification. And try to form proper clauses/sentences. It helps.

Answer (score 2):

Tab Controls are NOT the same as Navigation Controls! Tabs Ctrls hold separate forms on each page or tab, which means when the main form loads it loads ALL the sub-forms that are contained on the various pages of the TabCtrl.

Sadly Nav Ctrls were introduced in A2010, however, I've been using them since 2003. Well obviously not exactly because they were introduced. But instead I used labels (not command buttons although you can use those - I chose labels because I wanted to change the background and font color of the selected "tab"). I also wrote a function that took the value of the label (aka subform name) and used that to change the form of a subform control which was placed directly below or beside the labels depending on whether I wanted a horizontal or vertical "nav ctrl".

I could upload the code for this, however, I believe, given that MS has given a better control than this work around AND you should be able to piece this together if you've got a basic working experience with VBA.